# How to implement a running clock in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am trying to make a simple app whereby a user selects a date/time in future and upon that date/time happening that a particular event happens.

How do I get about getting such a thing implemented?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about getting Notification such as Alarm??

If yes, Local Notification is the same that you want. For using it please go through demo explanation : http://www.iostipsandtricks.com/ios-local-notifications-tutorial/

and for API's see YusufX's answer...